# cannot click element after animation (I am out of guesses)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out why after building this metro grid http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoxzp, I cannot click the same square again if it has already been expanded. Would anyone be nice enough to help me with this?

```
var tile = $('.metro-grid > * ');
tile.on('click', function () {
    tile.not($(this))
        .addClass('fade-out')
        .addClass('hidden');
    $(this).removeClass('hidden')
        .addClass('flip')
        .addClass('exploded-tile');
    tile.not($(this))
        .addClass('hidden');
    $(this).children()
        .data('function', 'exploded_content')
        .removeClass('hidden');
    tile.click(revert);
});

function revert() {
    tile.removeClass('hidden')
        .removeClass('flip')
        .removeClass('exploded-tile')
        .removeClass('fade-out');
    $('[data-function="exploded_content"]').removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden')
}


<header>Click to expand / Click again to close.. But try clicking the same tile after it has been restored to its default state</header>
<div id="main" role="main">
  <article class="metro-grid animated">
    <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become <a href="javascript:alert('!')">dfdfefef</a>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1550x1550/ffffff" alt="" />
      </div>
    </section>
       <section class="large-tile">
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section class="medium-tile">
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>

       <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
       <section class="large-tile">
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section class="medium-tile">
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>
     <section>
      <h1>Tile title</h1>
      <h2>Tile subtitle</h2>
      <div class="hidden" data-function="exploded_content">
        This is additional stuff that will become hidden
      </div>
    </section>

  </article>

<!--  <button onclick="revert()" style="position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 10;">Revert</button>-->
</div>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Show the markup **in** the question, not just linked.

Comment: Why add `hidden` to the elements that aren't `$(this)` twice? (Side note: There's no reason to do `.not($(this))`, `.not(this)` is sufficient.

Comment: Before calling `tile.click(revert);`, I would remove the original listener to prevent both handlers from firing: `$(this).off('click'); $(this).click(revert);` You can have the `revert` function re-add the listener to that element.

Comment: Also note that *every time* you click a tile, you're adding a new handler for `click` events on all elements in `tile` that calls `revert`.

Comment: @nbrooks: It's deterministic if you use jQuery: It's in the order in which they were attached. (It's also deterministic if you don't use jQuery, but the deterministic order varies from browser to browser.) (But the OP almost certainly doesn't want to repeatedly add handlers.)

Comment: you down voted me for not having enough code? really? How is that constructive, and why not wait 10 min before doing so? (thanks for the rest of the feedback however, am about to try off.('click')... ) I still dont have the css does that mean I get downvoted again?

Comment: @user2626009: You don't know who downvoted the question (not *you*, the *question*), nor why. People on SO downvote, and people on SO comment. It's rare that they're the same person. If you assume you know who the down (or indeed up) voters are, you **will** be wrong more often than right. (For instance, as the majority commenter, if you were assuming it was me who downvoted the question, you were mistaken.) Pay attention to comments, and pay attention to downvotes, but don't assume they come from the same person.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I couldn't remember if there was a well-defined order of execution for the handlers. You're correct though, OP probably doesn't want multiple handlers bound to an element counteracting each other.

Comment: @user2626009 In addition to what others said, you can update `title.click(revert)` to `tile.one('click', revert )` and that will work (probably with the least amount of code change :)

Comment: no I dont, and I cannot get that the .off('click') method to help either, could anyone fork my codepen :p

Comment: Here's codepen forked using one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cDkCg

Comment: *"(I am out of guesses)"* Don't guess; *debug*. There's a debugger built into your browser. Open it, set a break point in your code, and step through it. Watch what happens. Make sure you've read the documentation for the methods you're calling. Think about what the methods you're calling do, and why they may be having the effect you're seeing.

Comment: @user2626009 and one more forked code pen cleaned up a bit: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kmnAi (look into jQuery a bit more and you'll find it really eases your life with the convenience methods :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you flip you also bind a "revert" handler -

So the 2nd time you click it, it executes "flip" and "revert".

The 3rd time you click it, it executes "flip" and two "reverts".

A better solution - handle flip or revert based on the current status,
ie:

```
.on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('flip')) {
       // if already flipped - revert
       revert(); 
       return false;
    }
    // not flipped yet - do the flip!
    // - but don't bind revert handler to click at the end !
    ...
```

**Edit**:  Since you asked - I show here how its done your way - but for small stuff such as flip-revert a "if" statement in a single handler is so much more readable, less prone to bugs, etc...

To do it your way you'd have to unbind the previous click handlers like so:

```
function flip() { 
   // flip code here...
   $(this).off('click.flipper').on('click.flipper', revert);
}
function revert() {
   // revert code here...
   $(this).off('click.flipper').on('click.flipper', flip);
}
$('.metro-grid > *').on('click.flipper',flip);  // click handler with "flipper" event namespace
```

Comment: Ahh I like your style.. but I still want to know how to do it either way.

Comment: edited my answer to show how its done "your way" also - but as mentioned, this isn't recommended - it just complicates matters where a simple "if" would work.

Comment: actually -  @JackPattishallJr. solution is more elegant - using `.one('click', revert)` to bind revert and automatically unbind it once it is executed.

Comment: @Iftah: Already +1'd before the edit, but for the edit a namespaced event would probably be best (to avoid removing unrelated handlers).

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder!  I wasn't aware of namespaced events - definitely a better solution than remove all handlers.